# Data received from ajax get request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, recaptcha

I've got flask app and I'm trying to make a request from the client to backend and the other way round to validate ReCaptcha.

JS:

```
var onloadCallback = function() {

    var captchaCallback = function(param) {
        return $.get( "gettoken/" + param, function( data ) {
          window.console.log(data.toString())
          if (!data.success) {
              window.alert("something went wrong" + data.error);
          }
          else {
              $(".submitBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          }
        });
  };

  grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
  'sitekey' : 'secret_key',
    'callback' : captchaCallback
    });
};
```

PYTHON:

```
@app.route('/gettoken/<g_recaptcha_response>')
def verify_recaptcha(g_recaptcha_response):
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=secret_key&response=' + g_recaptcha_response) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        print(data)
        return data
```

Data printed in python method is correct `{'success': True, 'challenge_ts': '2019-11-07T11:07:22Z', 'hostname': 'localhost'}`. But then data printed back in js shows: `[object Object]`. How should I correctly read the data return from python `verify_recaptcha` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.toString applied for an object will return [object Object]

```
var myObj = {};
console.log(myObj.toString());
//returns [object Object]
```

Try to use object attributes directly, like this:

```
console.log(data.success);
```

And just as advice: never show your API keys on public

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The problem is calling `.toString()` on an object will return that. If you want to see a log with your object try with:

```
window.console.log(data)
```

or:

```
window.console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```